# Can a warlock ready an action to shatter an incoming arrow?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, combat, warlock, readied-action

A warlock is flying above the trees, and an enemy shoots him with an arrow. Fully expecting another arrow, can the warlock ready his shatter invocation to destroy the next arrow mid-air before it hits him? If so, how would the mechanics work? If not, why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Any spell can be readied to cast, so long as it has a cast time of 1 action, which shatter does. RAW, this is a valid use of the spell, and the arrow would take damage per the spell, since it is unattended while in flight. However, were I GMing, I would likely ask the warlock to make a Dexterity check to cast his invocation, as arrows are small, fast moving projectiles; a situation made worse by the foliage in the way. That said, I applaud the clever use of that spell.

Comment: Or maybe perhaps in a similar way an initiative check?

Comment: FrancisJohn what do you mean?